# CodeIgniter my photo can't be inserted into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my code, my photo can't be inserted into the database. I don't know where the problem is.

Controller:

```
public function add_gambar()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('gambar'))
        {
            $this->Gambarhome_model->tambah_gambar_error();
           redirect('gambarhome/','refresh');
        }
        else
        {

            $this->Gambarhome_model->tambah_gambar();
            redirect('gambarhome/','refresh');
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
function tambah_gambar(){
        $date = $this->upload->data();
        $data=array(
        'judul'=>$this->input->post('judul'),
        'desc'=>$this->input->post('desc'),
        'gambar'=>$date['file_name']
        );
        $this->db->insert('gambarhome',$data);
    }
```

Someone help me pls, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you load the upload library try to used this:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

and then try to upload the image with if condition.

Answer (score 0):

## Use BLOB data type

what data-type you have used to store your image in database table? Use LONGBLOB to store Binary Large Objects into a table. If you want to store more than size of 1Mb image file, you can achieve it by making necessary changes in server config file. Try LONGBLOB if you haven't used it.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/';
//make sure that you have given the correct path
```